# Question about covariant parameters in Java

Tags: java, covariance, covariant

I have this piece of code:

```
class X {
    int x = 1;
}

class Y extends X {
    int y = 2;
}

class Z extends Y {
    int z = 3;
}


class A {
    public Y metodo1(Y y) {
        System.out.println("Metodo1 de A");
        return new Y();
    }

    public Y metodo2(Y y) {
        System.out.println("Metodo2 de A");
        return new Y();
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public X metodo1(Y y) {
        System.out.println("Metodo1 de B");
        return new X();
    }

    public Z metodo2(Y y) {
        System.out.println("Metodo2 de B");
        return new Z();
    }

    public void metodo3() {
        System.out.println("Metodo3 de B");
    }
}

class C extends A{
    public Y metodo1(X x) {
        System.out.println("Metodo1 de C");
        return new Y();
    }

    public Y metodo2(Z z) {
        System.out.println("Metodo2 de C");
        return new Z();
    }

    public void metodo3() {
        System.out.println("Metodo3 de C");
    }
}

public class DynamicBinding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A b = new B();
        A c = new C();
        C c1 = new C();

        X x1 = b.metodo1(new Y());
        X x2 = b.metodo2(new Y());
        b.metodo3();

        X x3 = c.metodo1(new X());
        X x4 = c.metodo2(new Z());
        c.metodo3();

        X x5 = c1.metodo1(new Y());
        X x6 = c1.metodo1(new X());
    }
}
```

I know there are some errors like the covariant return type in

```
public X metodo1(Y y) {
      System.out.println("Metodo1 de B");
      return new X();
}
```

or that `b.metodo3();` doesn't exist, but my question is about this:

```
X x5 = c1.metodo1(new Y());
X x6 = c1.metodo1(new X());
```

Eclipse doesn't show me any errors, but I think that they have covariant arguments and that is not allowed in Java. What am I missing? (maybe in `X x5 = c1.metodo1(new Y());` it calls the metodo1 of A, but I don't understand the other one).

Thanks!

Comment: C has a method taking an X as argument. so the argument matches. And it returns an Y. An Y is an X, so you can assign the result to a variable of type X.

Comment: "*... that they have covariant arguments and that is not allowed in Java*" - Why should it not be allowed? `metodo1(X x)` in `C` does not override `medoto1(Y y)` in `A`, but overload it. You can verify this by adding `@Override` to `metodo1(...)` in class `C`. This will result in a compiler error.

Comment: Oh okay now I see it, it seems that I have misread the exercise :) Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method in a sub class is not allowed to break the contract in a super class, so lets assume you have

```
Class SuperClass{
  ReturnType method(ParameterType p) {..}
}
```

then any `SubClass` must either override method with

```
ReturnType method(ParameterType p) {..}
```

or

```
ReturnTypeSubclass method(ParameterType p) {..}
```

This ensures that when the class is used, there's no issues with types. The contract isn't broken with covariant return types, because `ReturnTypeSubClass` is a `ReturnType`.

---

If you implement method in `SubClass` like so:

```
AnyType method(ParameterTypeSubClass p) {..}
```

..you're not overriding it. You're overloading it. Now there are **two** method in `SubClass`. One is inherited from `SuperClass`.

Imagine if it was overriding it and someone used the class like so:

```
Super s = new SubClass;
s.method(new ParameterType());
```

an error would be thrown, because the overriding method would not be able to take a `ParameterType`, and the contract would be broken.

Comment: Yeah I knew the theory but it seems that the problem is that  I have misread the exercise. Anyways it's a very good explanation so I'll mark it as the correct answer, thanks!

Comment: @MarioR. Thank you. I tested it all before I posted it, just to make sure :)